# DocuSign API: Pre-filling radio group tabs for template

Tags: templates, tabs, docusignapi

I have radio groups setup in my DocuSign template, and am trying to fill it up while creating an envelope using the template. Here's the XML structure that I've made:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>******</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <templateId>******</templateId>
   <templateRoles>
      <templateRole>
         <email>******@test.com</email>
         <name>****** ******</name>
         <roleName>General</roleName>
         <clientUserId>UserId</clientUserId>
         <tabs>
            <textTabs>
               <text>
                  <tabLabel>Name</tabLabel>
                  <value>Test User</value>
               </text>
               <text>
                  <tabLabel>Address 1</tabLabel>
                  <value>123 Main Street</value>
               </text>
               <text>
                  <tabLabel>Address 2</tabLabel>
                  <value>Venice, CA 12345</value>
               </text>
            </textTabs>
            <radioGroupTabs>
               <radioGroup>
                  <groupName>Radio Group 1</groupName>
                  <radios>
                     <radio>
                        <selected>True</selected>
                        <value>Radio 1</value>
                     </radio>
                     <radio>
                        <selected>False</selected>
                        <value>Radio 2</value>
                     </radio>
                  </radios>
               </radioGroup>
            </radioGroupTabs>
         </tabs>
      </templateRole>
   </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Is this XML request correct? The 'Name' and 'Address *' tabs are correctly filled, but the radio group tabs are not filled at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML looks correct to me; in fact, I was able to copy/paste (including the **radioGroupTabs** portion) from your code sample into my own request and it works as desired -- i.e., the radio button specified as selected in the request is indeed selected when the recipient opens the envelope.

I'd suggest you verify that the values of **groupName**  and **value** (for each Radio) in the Request XML match ***exactly*** with the corresponding values specified for the Radio Button Tag Properties, as shown here in the DocuSign UI -- and keep in mind that values are ***case-sensitive***:

[image: Radio Button Tag Properties]